# Can not upload images in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Error is : You did not select a file to upload.

My controller:

```
        $image_name=$_FILES['screen_img']['name'];
        $config['upload_path']=FCPATH.'asset/project_images/';
        $config['allowed_types']='jpeg|jpg|png';
        $config['overwrite']=true;
        $config['max_size']="2048000";
        $config['file_name']=$image_name;
        $config['max_height']="768";
        $config['max_width']="1024";
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload($image_name))
        {
         $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
         print_r($error);
         $this->load->view('screen/new_screen', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
             print_r($data);
            $this->load->view('screen/new_screen',$data);
        }
```

My view

```
<?php  echo  form_open_multipart('screen/new_screen')?>
<input type="file" class="form-control"  name="screen_img" /><br>
<input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="submit">
<?php  echo form_close();?>
```

I was try all examples of internet but they did not work. I can not find issue.

Comment: check out put of these 
1. print_r($_FILE);
2. print_r($this->upload) see file_name

Comment: $image_name=$_FILES['screen_img']['name'];  this for get file name  and its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write field name in do_upload function

```
if(!$this->upload->do_upload("screen_img"))
```

instead of `$_FILES['screen_img']['name'];`